# How to add resources to WSO2 GReg using the Admin Services

Tags: wso2

I would like to know how to add resources to WSO2 GReg using the Admin Services. I would like to do things like:

- Add a resource
- Add a collection
- Add a life cycle

In addition I would like to be able to use the Admin Services to:

- Add an application
- Add a feature to GReg

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 0):

There is a Web service API with WSO2 Governance registry that can be used to do such registry related functions. you can find the WSDL of this service from here

> https://{IP}:{Port}/services/WSRegistryService.wsdl

Also there is a sample client that you can try out. Doc is [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/WS-API+Sample). I have seen that Governance registry documentation contain good samples that can be tried out.

Comment: Hi Asela. Thx for the quick response. I found the actions I need (WSnewCollection and WSnewResource), but the WSDL doesn't give much help what elements need to be passed. Can you provide me with an working example I can use in SoapUI? Thx!

Comment: In Governance registry pack, you can find the sample in  GREG_HOME/samples/ws-client directory...  Else you can use SOAPUI as always

Comment: Hi Asela. I got the exammple working. What I don't understand, how do I use this example to understand calling the admin services using SoapUI?